# Номер появления слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Изучаю Python на курсере и не могу заметить ошибку в коде при решении следующей задачи:
Во входном файле (вы можете читать данные из файла input.txt) записан текст. Словом считается последовательность непробельных подряд идущих символов. Слова разделены одним или большим числом пробелов или символами конца строки. Для каждого слова из этого текста подсчитайте, сколько раз оно встречалось в этом тексте ранее.

Формат ввода

Вводится текст.

Формат вывода

Выведите ответ на задачу.

Пример:
Входные данные:
one two one tho three

Вывод программы:
0 0 1 0 0

Когда тестирую код то ответ правильный однако курсера пишет что ответ не правильный. Прошу подсказать конкретно в какой части кода у меня ошибка.

Мой код:

```
#  Открываем файл с данными, создаем словарь и список
fin = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
words = dict()
letterWord = []
# создаем список слов из текста в файле fin
for line in fin.readlines():
    for word in line.split(' '):
        letterWord.append(word)
#  убираем в словах списка лишние знаки
nList = []
for word in letterWord:
    nList.append(word.rstrip('\n').strip('.').strip(',').strip(';'))

#  формируем словарь с количеством одинаковых слов в списке
for i in nList:
    words[i] = words.get(i, 0) + 1
    print(words[i] - 1, end=' ') #  выводим номер появления слова
fin.close()
```

Comment: А Вы пробовали разные комбинации символов-разделителей или только  по одному пробелу ставили между словами? Может загвоздка в том что их по условию может быть больше чем один, либо комбинация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моя гипотеза: про точку и остальные разделители в условии не говорилось -
поэтому "one" и "...one" на курсере может считаться как 2 разных слова - а у вас считается как одно и тоже.
Вам следует убрать "очистку от ненужных знаков".